# Mate desktop 20.04 hovering panel thumbnail causes excessive CPU usage

Tags: cpu, mate, thumbnails

Observed on Mate 20.04 .iso install, host and VM.

When I hover over the windows on the panel, it is supposed to generate a thumbnail for the window. When that works correctly, there is no problem(seemingly).
When the thumbnail for the window does not generate, the CPU usage goes excessively high, and remains that way until I move the cursor away from the offending window.
The process is wnck-applet that is shown to be spiking.

I resolved this by (on the panel) opening "Window List Preferences" and selecting "Hide thumbnails on hover".

Though I am not a huge fan of the feature, it has been somewhat useful on my work desktop where I have a ton of windows...

Is there any known fixes out there to make the thumbnails consistently show when hovered over?

The Wu

Answer (score -3):

I highly recommend a window manager called Compiz.

Here is how to install it:

If you don't have Synaptic installed then you gotta do it from Terminal:

sudo apt install synaptic

then enter password

Now run Synaptic: Main Menu: System ⯈ Administration ⯈ Synaptic Package Manager.  (then enter password)

In Synaptic search for a package called: compiz. Find the package and install it and any other recommended packages by clicking on the box and select "mark for installation". Then just click Apply at the top to install it.  Do the same for the package called: compizconfig-settings-manager.  Once installed you can close Synaptic.

Now run Mate-Tweak.  Its in Main Menu: System⯈ Preferences⯈ Look and Feel⯈ Mate Tweak.  In Mate Tweak Click on the Windows icon.  In the drop down menu under "Window manager" select Compiz(Advanced GPU accelerated desktop effects)

Now run CompizConfig Settings Manager.  Its in Main Menu: System⯈ Preferences⯈ Look and Feel⯈ CompizConfig Settings Manager.

In the Compiz Settings page look for EXTRAS: "Thumbnail Window Previews" and check the box. Now when you hover over the panel there will be thumbnails. Compiz thumbnails also play video like if a video is playing in VLC its thumbnail will be a small video.

I also highly recommend other effects in Compiz like: "Desktop Cube" and "3D Windows".  I can activate it by pressing the ctrl and super keys on my keyboard and then by clicking and dragging on my screen i can rotate the cube desktop. You can select any key combo you want to activate it because compiz is customizable.

One day all linux distros will have Compiz preinstalled.

Linux Forever

Comment: MATE doesn't use Compiz (which is a window manager - CCSM is a settings manager for Compiz) so one would have to install Compiz to attempt this answer (also, why install synaptic when apt can install the package?)

Comment: Just trying to make the Linux community a better place by keeping instructions clear and easy to follow for new users. Sorry for trying to be helpful.